# take picture continuously in android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am new to android. I just downloaded an example camera program. I can take one image each time I click the "capture" button.

Now I want to know if it is possible to take two images continuously (one with flash and one without flash). Does anybody have a hint on how to do that? Thanks a lot.

I posted the sample code here:

```
public class AndroidCameraExample extends Activity {
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private PictureCallback mPicture;
private Button capture, switchCamera;
private Context myContext;
private LinearLayout cameraPreview;
private boolean cameraFront = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    myContext = this;
    initialize();
}

private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
    int cameraId = -1;
    // Search for the front facing camera
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            cameraId = i;
            cameraFront = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return cameraId;
}

private int findBackFacingCamera() {
    int cameraId = -1;
    //Search for the back facing camera
    //get the number of cameras
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    //for every camera check
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
            cameraId = i;
            cameraFront = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return cameraId;
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!hasCamera(myContext)) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone does not have a camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        finish();
    }
    if (mCamera == null) {
        //if the front facing camera does not exist
        if (findFrontFacingCamera() < 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            switchCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }           
        mCamera = Camera.open(findBackFacingCamera());
        mPicture = getPictureCallback();
        mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
    }
}

public void initialize() {
    cameraPreview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(myContext, mCamera);
    cameraPreview.addView(mPreview);

    capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    capture.setOnClickListener(captrureListener);

    switchCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ChangeCamera);
    switchCamera.setOnClickListener(switchCameraListener);
}

OnClickListener switchCameraListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //get the number of cameras
        int camerasNumber = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        if (camerasNumber > 1) {
            //release the old camera instance
            //switch camera, from the front and the back and vice versa

            releaseCamera();
            chooseCamera();
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone has only one camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
};

public void chooseCamera() {
    //if the camera preview is the front
    if (cameraFront) {
        int cameraId = findBackFacingCamera();
        if (cameraId >= 0) {
            //open the backFacingCamera
            //set a picture callback
            //refresh the preview

            mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);                
            mPicture = getPictureCallback();            
            mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
        }
    } else {
        int cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
        if (cameraId >= 0) {
            //open the backFacingCamera
            //set a picture callback
            //refresh the preview

            mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);
            mPicture = getPictureCallback();
            mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //when on Pause, release camera in order to be used from other applications
    releaseCamera();
}

private boolean hasCamera(Context context) {
    //check if the device has camera
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private PictureCallback getPictureCallback() {
    PictureCallback picture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            //make a new picture file
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();

            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                //write the file
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Picture saved: " + pictureFile.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            //refresh camera to continue preview
            mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
        }
    };
    return picture;
}

OnClickListener captrureListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
    }
};

//make picture and save to a folder
private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
    //make a new file directory inside the "sdcard" folder
    File mediaStorageDir = new File("/sdcard/", "JCG Camera");

    //if this "JCGCamera folder does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        //if you cannot make this folder return
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    //take the current timeStamp
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    //and make a media file:
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

    return mediaFile;
}

private void releaseCamera() {
    // stop and release camera
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How precisely are you planning on having a flash and not a flash at the same time? Either the flash is on or off -- it is not simultaneously both on *and* off. Unless the Android device is in a box, and your last name is Schrödinger, and the Android device is really a cat.

Comment: Which devices do you intend to support? Note that *[camera2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)* allows much faster capture of full size still images than the old API, for which your sample code was written. But camera2 is only supported on Lollipop devices.

Comment: Actually, I want to take a picture without flash first, after that I want to take another picture with flash. I want to take two picture continuously, so I just need to push the button once.

Comment: I am using Galaxy s4